# Why does my c++ code does not show any output?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I am studying the c++ primer book and doing exercise 5.14. The exercise is:

Write a program to read strings from standard input
looking for duplicated words. The program should find places in the input
where one word is followed immediately by itself. Keep track of the largest
number of times a single repetition occurs and which word is repeated. Print
the maximum number of duplicates, or else print a message saying that no
word was repeated. For example, if the input is
how now now now brown cow cow the output should indicate that the word now occurred three times.

My code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
string pre_word, word, max_repeate_word;
int repeate_times = 0; max_repeate_times = 0;
while (cin >> word) {
    if (word == pre_word) {
        ++repeat_times;
    }
    else {
        repeat_times = 1;
        pre_word = word;
    }

    if (max_repeat_times < repeat_times) {
        max_repeat_times = repeat_times;
        max_repeat_word = pre_word;
    }
}

if (max_repeat_times <= 1) {
    cout << "no word was repeated" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "the word '" << max_repeat_word << "' occurred " << max_repeat_times << " times" << endl;
}
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? The program does not show any output when I input any string.

Comment: Recommendation: cut and paste code into Stack Overflow. When you type it in, the odds of inserting new mistakes is quite high.

Comment: And at three mistakes I'm giving up. Both `max_repeate_word` and `max_repeat_times` are used multiple times and I'm not sure if they're supposed to be the same thing or different variables or something else entirely.

Comment: One last thought: How are you signaling to the program that you've stopped giving it input? `cin` is a stream, so `while (cin >> word)` will keep going back for more words even after you stop typing. This could be your problem.

Comment: _"Is there anything wrong with my code that the programme does not show any output when I input any string."_ Yes, it can't be compiled because of syntax errors. After fixing the errors it works as expected:https://wandbox.org/permlink/hg2vOnKHyu67H9bJ Do you know how to send EOF to your program? You can either pipe the input into your program or send EOF with CTRL+D (for *nix) or CTRL+Z (for Windows) if your IDE/terminal supports it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cin >> word)
```

This stop only with EOF, you need to add a stop condition.
Example:

```
while (cin >> word && word != "")
```

Comment: Right idea, but proposed code won't work. By default `cin >> word` skips all whitespace so you can't get an empty string. You can change this behaviour, but searching for a canary value like "ZZZZ" is probably easier.

Comment: I don't see any problem with `while (cin >> word)`. You can send EOF with CTRL+D (for *nix) or CTRL+Z (for Windows)